# Add-In Development for iWork Applications

Tags: objective-c, excel, macos, applescript, iwork

Is there a COM equivalent API/SDK for developing custom apps for iWork (specifically Numbers) or Mac Excel. I have found that there is only Apple Script (but support for which has been diminished) but I don't think this will be enough for thr real-time financial applications I would like to create.

If there is no COM equivalent API/SDK, what is the preferred way, if any, of achieving such programmatic control over applications in the iWork suite (or Mac Excel)?

Things I would like to achieve, for example, are:

- Writing to sheets, cells and ranges
- Pulling data from external real-time sources (sockets etc.)
- Adding custom controls such as ribbons in excel

Thanks

Comment: For those of us not familiar with COM, can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, see edit above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applescript support was added back to Numbers 3.1 after being removed in Numbers '13. As long as you have '09 or 3.1, Applescript support would not be a problem.

It sounds like you're trying to write the application as a layer over a running version of Numbers/Excel, and not really as a standalone application. In that case, it sounds like your best bet may be using VBA for Mac with Excel. I'm not very familiar with VBA, but [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522048/customizing-a-ribbon-with-vba-in-excel) has some example code for making a custom toolbar, and [this forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/530006-excel-listening-socket.html) has example socket code. VBA also allows you to create Macros for working with sheets, cells, and ranges.

If you want a standalone app, you could split the domains into separate languages. Use Objective-C/Bash/Python for the socket stuff, Applescript for manipulating spreadsheets, and VBA for GUI elements.